# Show products on homepage magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, cms, product-list, rwd-theme

Just installed magento 1.9 and have fallen on the first hurdle.
I've created a product and have used suggestions from previous versions to display the product on the homepage but am getting the following message

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `getSortedChildren()` on a non-object in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` on line 180

Any help gratefully received.

In the content section of homepage I have...

```
<div class="page-title"> 
    <h2>Our Latest Products</h2> 
</div> 
<p>{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</p>
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the code you've used to add the products?

Comment: Hi I've used the same as I do for version 8. In the content section of homepage I have...<div class="page-title">
<h2>Our Latest Products</h2>
</div>
<p>{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</p>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is the new rwd design has two child blocks for the product list:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
```

And in the template itself there are not checks to see if these are present before they are attempted to be loaded and used.

A quick fix would be to use a different template that is a copy of the main template but with the following edits:

```
<?php
$_nameAfter = $this->getChild('name.after');
// New if here
if($_nameAfter):
    $_nameAfterChildren = $_nameAfter->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
        ?>
        <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
//set product collection on after blocks
$_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after');
if ($_afterChildren):
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName):
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
    ?>
    <?php echo $_afterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The `name.after` occurs twice in the template but the `after` appears just one. One final thing to note is that the default rwd css hides the actions section of the product list on the cms pages.

Comment: Can you please point in which file this code has to be added in rwd theme?

Comment: Adding what file would help, as well as lines. The above does not match the code in the list.phtml

Comment: Hi philip it could be that the most recent version of magento has fixed this problem.

Comment: which main template needs to be copied? list.phtml?