# only one product showing in list

Tags: product-list, ce-1.9.0.1, home

First Magento Site.
This has been the most difficult CMS to jump into it seems.
Brand new Magento install. 1.9.0.1

I've added this to my home page as suggested in other threads to create a product list on the home page.
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="2" products_count="400" column_count="6" template="catalog/product/list2.phtml"}}

I get what looks like an attempt to create a list but it seems the foreach isn't looping and the page gets cut off.  Only one product lists.  I thought this may be CSS related and they might be stacking.  But it actually only has one product listed in the code.

I've followed steps here:
[Show products on homepage magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9)

I've checked to make sure all are visible, enabled, default category etc.
http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/

also, none of the details are listing like in the old default Magento template.
products list fine when using the old default template vs. RWD template.

At a loss.
[image: list products not displaying Magento homepage]

as you can see from the image I have 28 items which it recognizes but its only listing one.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue and wondering if I should just abandon ship...

Comment: Any errors in your logs? it appears that there is an error when showing the first product so that it cannot continue rendering.