# "There are no products matching the selection"

Tags: product, magento-1.9, home, products-view

In magento at my home page i have added the the product block

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

And i have added two products with different categories moreover included both the products into a default_category (id:2)

But still i am getting that message so how can i display the products on my home page. I have set the quantity to 5 and 15. Still i dont get those products.

Flushed cached and Re-Indexed them

Looking for help ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the visibility of the products?

Comment: Actually i am new to magento, well the visibility is search, catalog

Comment: Nm that, no products matching the selection. Next up: are they 'enabled'. You checked stock, so this is pretty much what is left.

Comment: Yup they are enabled. I installed the sample data its all working now. That means I was somewhere wrong at configuration.

Comment: are you sure the products assigned to the category whose id is 2?

Comment: Yeah the id is 2 moreover i had add a snippet of all products too still there was nothing for the first code block too

Comment: do you see the products when you access that category on frontend

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show products on homepage magento 1.9](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9)

Comment: well I didn't got a menu and product in any category. The issue was i didn't assigned them to a default_category tree.

Answer (score 10):

Please check following settings are done for your product

1. The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2. The products must be Enabled.
3. Product must have a stock Quantity.
4. The product must be set to In Stock.
5. If the product is set not to track stock, it still need to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
6. The product must be assigned to the target Category.
7. If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
8. You must refresh your “var/Cache” & rebuild all indexes from admin > system > index management

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Did all the steps, but it does still show **There are no products matching the selection.** Im on a fresh Magento 1.9.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to show specific category product on homepage.

```
$catid = $this->getCategoryId();

$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);

$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
               ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
               ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
               ->setOrder('position','Asc');


if ($_products->getSize()): 

 $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>

  echo $_product->getName();

endforeach; 

endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your products were initially showing and then suddenly disappeared, then you must change product as new to date. Go to catalog>Products>General and then change the dates to a later one (depends on your arex product tab settings) because once the date passes away, the products start moving away from the home page tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I started a fresh magento 1.9.4.4 installation and added a new category and then I added a grouped product and a simple product. I linked the simple product to the group product and then I linked the group product to the category. But nothing showed.

I also followed the [troubleshooting list](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/49015/66769) by from mrumair.com, but nothing worked.

I figured out, that my grouped product was not showing, because I added a "Custom option" to my simple product.